Method not found exception from Dynamics 365 Plugin
I am writing a plugin Package that includes Plugin dll and dependent Azure libraries to request PFX certificate from the Azure Key Vault. After receiving the certificate from the KeyVault, a request is made to the SOAP service along with this certificate. The code works well in the console application but it throws error when executed in the plugin package deployed in Dynamics 365 environment.
I tried deploying the package using Plugin Registration Toolkit as well as Power Platform Tools but getting the same error
Isolation Mode: Sandbox (Cannot change for the plugin package)
Namespaces Used:
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

Exception Thrown:
Exception Message: **Method not found: 'Void Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates.CertificateClient..ctor(System.Uri, Azure.Core.TokenCredential)'.**<br/>
ErrorCode: -2147220956 <br/>
HexErrorCode: 0x80040224

> HelpLink: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398563&error=Microsoft.Crm.CrmException%3a80040224&client=platform

TraceText:<br/> \[SOAPRequest.GetAccountNumberPlugin: SOAPRequest.Account.GetAccountNumber\]<br/> \[28c85a71-b44f-ef11-a317-000d3a125c0b: SOAPRequest.Account.GetAccountNumber: Create of account\]<br/> Starting sync workflow 'New business rule', Id: 1924900e-9b42-ef11-840a-000d3a8f88eb<br/> Entering Condition Step1_step:<br/> Sync workflow 'New business rule' completed successfully<br/> \[+3,999ms\] - Entered SOAPRequest.Account.GetAccountNumber.Execute() Correlation Id: 4b9511c0-6750-4d6f-b9f6-6b16f3821884, Initiating User: 4440f24b-580d-ef11-9f89-7c1e520ce8ac, Correlation Id: 4b9511c0-6750-4d6f-b9f6-6b16f3821884, Initiating User: 4440f24b-580d-ef11-9f89-7c1e520ce8ac<br/> \[+344ms\] - Exiting SOAPRequest.Account.GetAccountNumber.Execute(), Correlation Id: 4b9511c0-6750-4d6f-b9f6-6b16f3821884, Initiating User: 4440f24b-580d-ef11-9f89-7c1e520ce8ac<br/> Activity Id: 08bef23e-0a1a-4cd1-95c5-ed1291da61c9<br/>

Additional Points that I analysed:

The method is available in the library. Confirmed it by checking the metadata by clicking on the class from Visual Studio.
If the method is not available it should have thrown in the console application too. But it works like a charm when executed in console
I could not find any alternative solution to handle this requirement as Dynamics 365 does not recommend ILMerge and the only way is to use Pluginpackage

